# ay Array in python not getting updated

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Following is the code where in caller is called first from another module,
centroids is of float type (an array of numberofcluster * numberoffeatures)
labels is 1d array of numberofexplanations

array is not getting updated

```
def caller(centroids, labels):

    number_of_features = len(centroids[0])
    one_column = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    i = 0
    j = 0

    array = [[0 for x in xrange(number_of_features)] for x in xrange(5)]

    while i < number_of_features:
        j = 0
        while j < 5:
            one_column[j] = centroids[j][i]
            j += 1

        rank(one_column, i, array)
        i += 1 


    return calculatemean(number_of_features, array)


def rank(one_column, ithfeature, array):

    temp_dict = {}
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
         temp_dict[one_column[i]] = i
         i += 1

    number_of_uniquevalues = len(set(temp_dict))
    sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(temp_dict.items()))

    i = 0
    keys_list = sorted_dict.keys()

    while i < 5:
        array[one_column.index(keys_list[i])][ithfeature] = sorted_dict[keys_list[i]]
        i += 1
```

Comment: Which Array in this python code not getting updated?

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to this link

[Two dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183146/two-dimensional-array-in-python?rq=1)

and the issue is resolved