# How can I build a two or multidimensional list from already available one dimension list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list below.  I would like to create a two or multidimensional list from one dimension normal list

`x= [ light, double , motor , boolean , brakes , unit 8]`

I would like to see like that

`x= [ [light, double] , [motor , boolean] , [brakes , unit 8]]`

in this way I can select and check the type of specific signal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183146/two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way using `numpy array`

```
import numpy as np
x= [ 'light', 'double' , 'motor' , 'boolean' , 'brakes' , 'unit 8']
a = np.array(x).reshape(3,2)
# print(a) will print as numpy array
# for printing as a list
print(a.tolist())
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way I know of:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

In Python 2 you can drop the `list`.

To help see what's going on:

```
>>> x[::2]
[1, 3, 5]
>>> x[1::2]
[2, 4, 6]
```

This is called slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice and the zip the list like this:

```
zip(x[::2], x[1::2])
```

This will generate a list of two-element tuples.