# Insert value at random place in 2D list

Tags: python, list, 2d, minesweeper

I'm trying to make a minesweeper game using lists in python. I have have this code so far:

```
import random as r
import sys

#dimension of board and number of bombs
width = int(sys.argv[1])
height = int(sys.argv[2])
b = int(sys.argv[3])

#creates the board
board = [[0.0] * width] * height

#places bombs
for i in range(b):
    x = r.randint(0, width - 1)
    y = r.randint(0, height - 1)
    board.insert(x, y, 0.1)

#prints board
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board[i]))
        print(board[i][j], end=" ")
```

I'm trying to get the bombs to be placed at random places on the board, but `insert()` only accepts 2 args. Is there any other way in which I can do this?

I have an idea to place a random bomb in row 1, then a random bomb in row 2, and so on and once it hits row n it loops back to row 1 until enough bombs have been placed, but I'm not sure if it will work (and I have no way of testing it because I have do idea how to do that either). I feel like this solution is pretty inefficient, so I'm also wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `board[x][y] = 0.1` to access index `y` in row `x` of your board. Also, you don't want to build a board like that. The way you're doing it will only actually create 1 array with numbers. Here's your code with some modifications.

```
import random as r

# dimension of board and number of bombs
# (I'm using hard coded values as an example)
width = 5
height = 7
b = 10

#creates the board
board = []
for i in range(height): # create a new array for every row
    board.append([0.0] * width)

#places bombs
for i in range(b):
    x = r.randint(0, height - 1)
    y = r.randint(0, width - 1)
    board[x][y] = 0.1 # this is how you place a bomb at a random coordinate

#prints board
for row in board:
    print(row)
```

The resulting board for me looks like:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]                                                                                                                        
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]                                                                                                                        
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]                                                                                                                        
[0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1]                                                                                                                        
[0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]                                                                                                                        
[0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]                                                                                                                        
[0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Note that you can end up with less than `b` bombs in case the random x and y values repeat. That's a good problem to solve next.

Answer (score 1):

Use assignment instead of insert:
`board[x][y] = 0.1`.

Also, be careful initializing your 2D board. `board = [[0.0] * width] * height` will make one list of size `width` and then will copy pointers to that list for all of the `height` i.e. if you assign 0.1 to the first cell in the first row `board[0][0]` the first item in *every* row will be assigned since they are all the same list. you have to instead use

```
   board = [[0.0]*width for _ in range(height)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We are dealing list of list. If we run your board initialization code and modify board value as follows:

```
>>> width = 2; height = 3
>>> board = [[0.0] * width] * height
>>> print board
[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
>>> x = 0; y = 1; board[y][x] = 1.1
>>> print board
[[1.1, 0.0], [1.1, 0.0], [1.1, 0.0]]
```

We see our modification appears three places. This is because we have put the same list ([0.0] * width) *height* times. One way of doing it properly is board = [[0.0] * width for _ in range(3)]. Please refer to [Two dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183146/two-dimensional-array-in-python) .

Since we are using list of list, one way of inserting element 0.1 for x and y will be using insert will be board[y].insert(x, 0.1). But I feel like that what you wanted to do is board[y][x]=0.1.

For the placing bombs, what you have described can be implemented like:

```
n = <the number of bombs>
for i in xrange(n):
    x = i % width  # x will iterate over 0 to width
    y = r.randint(0, height - 1)
    # insert bomb
```

Cheers,